# How to disabled ADD TO CART button when user had not checked the zipcode

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, zipcode

I am building an e-commerce website named ["bookslab.in"](http://www.bookslab.in).

My old exceptions are working fine for my "Add to cart" button.

I want to add one new exception to my "Add to cart" button. **I found this error last night.**

**Error:** If user enters the zipcode in zip code field & without clicking on **CHECK** button, when he clicks on **ADD TO CART** button then products are getting added in Shopping cart. I had the exceptions (not related to this new exception) which is working fine, but now I want to add a new exception.

*I want to make it compulsory for every user to check the zip code.* Because i am providing my service to the limited areas.

**Can we do this thing:**
If user enters the invalid zipcode in textfield & then he clicks on ADD TO CART button then directly an error message should be shown "Zipcode is invalid". No need to check the zipcode again by clicking on CHECK button.

I want to make the "*Add to cart*" button **freeze** if user does not check the zip code field. Please provide the code & file name & in which section to add the provided code. I had provided the view.phtml & cod.phtml. Any help will be appreciated. Any answer stacky's.

**view.phtml**

```
<?php
/*

 */
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-essential">
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
            <div class="no-display">
                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="product-img-box">
                <div class="product-name">
                    <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
            </div>

            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="product-name">
                    <span class="h1"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></span>
                </div>

                <div class="price-info">
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                </div>

                <div class="extra-info">
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false)?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_availability'); ?>
                </div>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>

                <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                    <div class="short-description">
                        <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>




                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                <?php endif;?>

            </div>

            <div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

                <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                            <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <div class="add-to-box">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>

            <div class="clearer"></div>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
            productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    var form = this.form;
                    var oldUrl = form.action;

                    if (url) {
                       form.action = url;
                    }
                    var e = null;
                    try {

                    this.form.submit();

                     } catch (e) {
                    }
                    this.form.action = oldUrl;
                    if (e) {
                        throw e;
                    }

                    if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                        button.disabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

            productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
                if(this.validator) {
                    var nv = Validation.methods;
                    delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                    // Remove custom datetime validators
                    for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                        if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                            delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                        }
                    }

                    if (this.validator.validate()) {
                        if (url) {
                            this.form.action = url;
                        }
                        this.form.submit();
                    }
                    Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
        <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
            <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                    <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                    <dd class="tab-container">
                        <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>

</div>
```

**cod.phtml**

```
<?php
/***************************************
 *** Cash On Delivery ***
 ***************************************
 */

$msgData = Mage::helper('netgo_cod')->getConfigData(); 
if($msgData['zip_status'] == 1){
?>
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="z-btn">
        <label>Zip Code : </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod" class="product-custom-option required-entry" id="cod" size="29" style='color:black; font-size:12px'>
        <button type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span><span>Check</span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="cod_msg"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkCOD(){
             var zipcode;
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);

                    if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1)
                                        {
                                          zipcode='checked';
                                          jQuery('.btn-cart').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
                                        }
                                      else
                                      {
                                      jQuery('.btn-cart').removeAttr('disabled');

                                      }

                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: what code of `netgo/cod/check`

Comment: the cod.phtml code is for zipcode section

Comment: booskslab.in not working

Comment: It is working fie

Comment: What type of error you are getting

Comment: @Julian Lachal, the function provided by you does not work.

Comment: I had already done that @Nits. The code provided by Amit is the thing i am looking, bu after adding his code my ADD TO CART button is not working

Comment: @SalmanDalal can you please provide zipcode to access or available shipping.

Comment: What i did not understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a simple solution you can disable add to cart button by default.

**If some one check valid zipcode then only he/she can able to do add to cart**

for this you can add below code in cod.phtml

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery('.btn-cart').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any solution other than this

Comment: @SalmanDalal waht is the problem with this solution

Comment: Users will get confused what they have to do to order if they see disabled shopping cart

Comment: @SalmanDalal you will make note on your site check zipcode then add to cart

Comment: Okzz i will check your idea, but please suggest me some thing except this because my website online now

Answer (score 0):

You could do javascript validations on click of add to cart button.
Or make backend validation by some hidden parameters before add to cart and check that zipcode checked or not.

Comment: So how to to this

Comment: First let me know that you have done just javascript code for validations? As mentioned above like disable / enable add-to-cart button.?

Comment: I had done validation, but now i have to add the new exception. That validations are for the old exceptions

Comment: My old exceptions are working as well

Answer (score 0):

you code of cod.phtml

```
 <?php
/***************************************
 *** Cash On Delivery ***
 ***************************************
 */

$msgData = Mage::helper('netgo_cod')->getConfigData(); 
if($msgData['zip_status'] == 1){
?>
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="z-btn">
        <label>Zip Code : </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod" class="product-custom-option required-entry" id="cod" size="29" style='color:black; font-size:12px'>
        <button type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span><span>Check</span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="cod_msg"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkCOD(){
             var zipcode;
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);

                    if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1)
                                        {
                                          zipcode='checked';
                                          if ( jQuery( ".cod-suc" ).length ) {
                                             jQuery('.button.btn-cart').css('display','block');
                                            }

                                            if ( jQuery( ".cod-error" ).length ) 
                                            {
                                             jQuery('.button.btn-cart').css('display','block');
                                            }
                                        }
                                      else
                                      {
                                           if ( jQuery( ".cod-suc" ).length ) 
                                            {
                                                jQuery('.button.btn-cart').css('display','block');
                                            }

                                            if ( jQuery( ".cod-error" ).length ) 
                                            {
                                             jQuery('.button.btn-cart').css('display','block');
                                            }
                                      }

                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<?php } ?>

<style>
.button.btn-cart {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Okzz i will check & update you

Comment: Your code does not work, & also your code removes all my old exception as well. Provide proper code

Comment: i just hide add to cart button. and on success i just check that cod-suc class is found or not if found than display add to cart button

Comment: but it is not working dude

Comment: Your code is working only for success, but for invalid code the ADD TO CART button is getting disabled.

Comment: ok you do for error as well as success return message??

Comment: i edit my answer you use that code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51054/discussion-between-jigs-parmar-and-salman-dalal).

Answer (score 0):

You need to some change in your code

You need remove the code  `var zipcode;` at from  checkCOD() but out side of this function

**So need to change**

**Change1:**

```
<script>
    function checkCOD(){
             var zipcode;
```

**to**

```
<script>
 var zipcode;
    function checkCOD(){
```

**Change2:**

```
if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1)
                                        {
                                          zipcode='checked';
                                          jQuery('.btn-cart').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
                                        }
                                      else
                                      {
                                      jQuery('.btn-cart').removeAttr('disabled');

                                      }
```

**to**

```
            if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1){
                zipcode='notavaliable';
                alert('Delivery of the book is not available')
                jQuery('.btn-cart').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
            }else{
                zipcode='checked';
                jQuery('.btn-cart').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
```

**Change 3:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
```

to

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if(  typeof zipcode !='undefined' &&  zipcode !='notavaliable'){
                alert('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode');
                 button.disabled = true;
                return false;
            }


            if(  typeof zipcode !='undefined' &&  zipcode !='checked'){
                alert('Please check pincode before  add to cart');
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: after following  your code add to cart button is not working

Comment: ADD TO CART button not working after adding your code

Comment: do  you have understood the code?

Comment: Yeap i understood